# Editor placeholder in source file error with simple UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode

I am totally new to Swift and also have no background experience in development. I am trying to a simply table view in Swift but keep getting the error 'Editor placeholder in source file.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: <#T##IndexPath#>) as! CustomCell

    cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
    cell.Name.text = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.Job.text = jobs[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where your problem is:

```
for: <#T##IndexPath#>)
```

just tab to that variable and type in:

```
indexPath
```

Comment: Cheers i think its just the way it copied and pasted!  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: IndexPath) as! CustomCell

Comment: indexPath, not IndexPath

Comment: So there were two problems: the placeholder (now you probably notice that before you enter a variable name it is highlighted, and tabbing brings you right to the variable), and case matters.

Comment: Thanks Mozahler :) yep that makes sense